# Creating a view to get name of student who obtained maximum mark in every course

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

Course table : courseId,courseName,tutor

Student table: studentId,studentName

Marks table: marksId,studentId,courseId,marks

If more info is needed plz comment

[image]

<\br>

```
CREATE VIEW maxmarks 
AS
SELECT b.studentName,courseId from [dbo].[zz_16_Marks_tbl] a,[dbo].[zz_16_Student_tbl] b
WHERE a.studentId=b.studentId AND marks in(
SELECT MAX(marks),courseId FROM [dbo].[zz_16_Marks_tbl] GROUP BY courseId)
```

Comment: can you please post what you have tried ?

Comment: Your title is ambiguous. Do you only want a row if the same student got the highest mark in all their classes? Or you want the name of the highest ranking student in each class? Can you show some sample data and desired output, so we have some clue if this is a pivot (where each student and their mark is listed as a column per class) or a normal resultset (where there is one row per class)?

Comment: Also it can be useful to specify what you want to do in the case of a tie - list both students, pick one arbitrarily, alphabetically, ...? So please make sure your sample data includes a tie and that your desired results show how you want to deal with it.

Comment: I want to find student with highest marks in each course

Comment: You can have a look at [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server). I think you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not sure whether/not to use joins for this. I am able to return max(marks) and courseId ... but not able to return the studentId since i am using group by... maybe i can post what i tried...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW maxmarks 
AS
WITH CTE AS (SELECT MAX(marks),courseId FROM [dbo].[zz_16_Marks_tbl] GROUP BY courseId )
SELECT b.studentName,a.courseId 
from [dbo].[zz_16_Marks_tbl] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[zz_16_Student_tbl] b ON a.studentId=b.studentId 
INNER JOIN CTE c ON a.courseId =c.courseId and a.marks=b.marks
```